# "Applications and Services" is missing from Failover Cluster Manager

Tags: cluster, windows-server-2012-r2, failover, failovercluster, windows-cluster

Microsoft instructions advise to use "Services and Applications" but it's missing from the Failover Cluster Manager.  For example, the documentation for [Test the Failover of a Clustered Service or Application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754577.aspx).  Where is the "Services and Applications" option/section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting after 2008 R2 Microsoft changed "Services and Applications" to "Roles".  Also in the referenced example, "Under Actions (on the right), click Move this service or application to another node" is now "Under Actions, click move, then either best possible node or select node".